# Next auth google login downloads page instead of navigating

Tags: next.js, google-oauth, next-auth, next.js13

I am using nextjs 13 (with the app directory beta enabled) as well as next-auth for authentication. Sometimes when trying to login with google instead of being redirected it just attempts to download the page

here is an example of my auth options for next-auth initialization

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { database } from "@/lib/database";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(database),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.name = token.name;
        session.user.email = token.email;
        session.user.image = token.picture;
        session.user.status = token.status as string;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      const dbUser = await database.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: token.email,
        },
      });

      if (!dbUser) {
        token.id = user.id;
        return token;
      }

      return {
        id: dbUser.id,
        name: dbUser.name,
        email: dbUser.email,
        picture: dbUser.image,
        status: dbUser.status,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

relavent frontend code:

```
import { signIn, getProviders } from "next-auth/react";

//....

<AuthButton
  onClick={() => signIn("google", {})}
>
   <FcGoogle size={20} /> Log in with Google
</AuthButton>
```

the file it downloads looks like this

```
J0:[[["",{"children":["(auth)",{"children":["login",{"children":["",{}]}]}]},null,null,true],"@1",[["$","title",null,{"children":"Storiway - The right way to tell your story"}],["$","meta",null,{"content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1","name":"viewport"}],["$","meta",null,{"name":"description","content":"Storiway provides an easy to use way to tell customers the stories of your brand."}],["$","link",null,{"rel":"icon","href":"/favicon.ico"}],["$","script",null,{"type":"text/javascript","async":true,"defer":true,"src":"/scripts/story-widget.js"}]]]]
M2:{"id":"9799","name":"","chunks":["544:d6e1aeb5-a0cd6c70e0c75eb3","541:541-9a7ed27eaa60a385","467:467-c3bf006142368b49","594:594-f55d59b38423cb14","621:621-562a0eec71b29bbf","531:531-61245aab4156da2f","493:493-763dfff1401403f4","929:929-d89874787c76a790","984:984-5d40795d22f21921","818:818-b6ce995c172fdce2","185:app/layout-c679f989968e7143"],"async":false}
M3:{"id":"9875","name":"","chunks":["272:webpack-b9aacdb8cf4e2fda","17:17-2f5f1c71a644e069","744:main-app-2aabd4f3728a103e"],"async":false}
M4:{"id":"2092","name":"","chunks":["272:webpack-b9aacdb8cf4e2fda","17:17-2f5f1c71a644e069","744:main-app-2aabd4f3728a103e"],"async":false}
M5:{"id":"2442","chunks":["994:b98bc7c3-8d93aa43aec73ea6","541:541-9a7ed27eaa60a385","594:594-f55d59b38423cb14","30:30-14a83a3970ed60db","299:299-17078d0866e06e38","665:app/(auth)/login/page-8cc2bf9fefe4ee19"],"name":"default","async":true}
J1:[[["$","link","static/media/2aaf0723e720e8b9.p.woff2",{"rel":"preload","href":"/_next/static/media/2aaf0723e720e8b9.p.woff2","as":"font","type":"font/woff2","crossOrigin":"anonymous"}]],[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/022c10a21f066f05.css","precedence":"high"}],["$","link","1",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/37f27c40047a1ec9.css","precedence":"high"}],["$","link","2",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/9a55bdf838cbf78d.css","precedence":"high"}],["$","link","3",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/1c7718005413b6f0.css","precedence":"high"}]],["$","html",null,{"lang":"en","className":"__variable_79e26d","children":[["$","head",null,{}],["$","body",null,{"className":"font-sans","children":["$","@2",null,{"children":["$","@3",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children"],"hasLoading":false,"template":["$","@4",null,{}],"notFound":["$","div",null,{"style":{"fontFamily":"-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, \"Segoe UI\", \"Fira Sans\", Avenir, \"Helvetica Neue\", \"Lucida Grande\", sans-serif","height":"100vh","textAlign":"center","display":"flex","flexDirection":"column","alignItems":"center","justifyContent":"center"},"children":[["$","head",null,{"children":["$","title",null,{"children":"404: This page could not be found."}]}],["$","div",null,{"children":[["$","style",null,{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML":{"__html":"\n            body { margin: 0; color: #000; background: #fff; }\n            .next-error-h1 {\n              border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);\n            }\n\n            @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {\n              body { color: #fff; background: #000; }\n              .next-error-h1 {\n                border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);\n              }\n            }\n          "}}],["$","h1",null,{"className":"next-error-h1","style":{"display":"inline-block","margin":0,"marginRight":"20px","padding":"0 23px 0 0","fontSize":"24px","fontWeight":500,"verticalAlign":"top","lineHeight":"49px"},"children":"404"}],["$","div",null,{"style":{"display":"inline-block","textAlign":"left","lineHeight":"49px","height":"49px","verticalAlign":"middle"},"children":["$","h2",null,{"style":{"fontSize":"14px","fontWeight":"normal","lineHeight":"49px","margin":0,"padding":0},"children":"This page could not be found."}]}]]}]]}],"childProp":{"current":["$","@3",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","(auth)","children"],"hasLoading":false,"template":["$","@4",null,{}],"childProp":{"current":["$","@3",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","(auth)","children","login","children"],"hasLoading":false,"template":["$","@4",null,{}],"childProp":{"current":[[],[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/1c7718005413b6f0.css","precedence":"high"}]],["$","@5",null,{"params":{},"searchParams":{}}]],"segment":""},"rootLayoutIncluded":true}],"segment":"login"},"rootLayoutIncluded":true}],"segment":"(auth)"},"rootLayoutIncluded":true}]}]}]]}]]
```

Not sure what to try. I am expecting to be redirected

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was an open issue on github, I had the same problems that you described.

• I updated to the latest version of next

• I added this snippet of code to my lowest-level layout (ssr), per a comment from the github thread.

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
export const revalidate = 0
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45595#issuecomment-1445878897

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).